# how to create an array of elements with 1 bit in size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, bit, bit-fields

In c / c++, we can define a variable with 1 bit in memory: like unsigned `char value : 1`;

Is there a way to declare an array of 1 bit elements? like in sudo code below:

```
unsigned char : 1 data[10];
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: Some related information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304723/c-a-scalable-number-class-bitset1-or-unsigned-char

Comment: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that in most implementations, the 1 bit variable will still occupy 1 byte of memory because that's the way the memory is addressed. If you have a big array of such values, however, then you can work around that. One such solution is `std::bitset`. You can make one like this:

```
#include <bitset>
std::bitset<64> data;
```

You can manipulate bits using the `set`, `reset` and `flip` operations (setting it to 1, 0 or toggling it). You can access a bit using `[]`, for instance

```
if (data[5]) { ...
```

Check out a nice example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset#Example).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however we cannot control the exact memory layout of std::bitset, as what we can with array.   for example sizeof(std::bitset<8>) or std::sizeof(std::bitset<64>) always return 8 bytes.  it limits its usage especially when we would like to use union to get bits of an integer.

Comment: And it is not efficient as array. std::bitset<> would use bit operations << or >> and & to get bit value at an index.  If we have no other choices, we might write our own bitset to control the memory layout. I am wondering whether we can define array with elements with size of 1 bit each that we donot need extra bit operations.

Comment: You could pack 8 bit fields (`unsigned int a: 1;`) into one `struct` and if you're lucky, the compiler will optimize it properly. You can then use those structs to make your own bitset. I wouldn't recommend it, however.

Comment: Yes, you are right, @Blaze. however if we do that, then we cannot access them by operator[] directly. We now need to do if else check to choose the correct bits. Branching is more costly than bit operations. branch mis-predict is about 3ns each referring to this url: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html

Comment: It seems array of 1 bit size element cannot be created in c / c++ for now. I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: How do you do this in C?

Comment: @ak_app see this answer for a rough idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372519/10411602